# Access Jenkins Credentials Environment Variables from Node.js

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I have set up some credentials environment variables using the Credentials plugin for Jenkins.
I am using them in my Jenkinsfile like this :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
      
      DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID          = credentials('DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID')
      DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET      = credentials('DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET')
     
  }
stages {
stage('Install dependencies') {
  steps {
      dir("./codes") {
            sh 'npm install'
        }
  }
}
stage('Stop previous forever process') {
  steps {
    dir("./codes") {
       sh 'forever stop dev || ls'
    }
  }
}
stage('Clean forever logs') {
    steps {
        dir("./codes") {
            sh 'forever cleanlogs'
        }
    }
}
stage('Test ') {
    steps {
        dir("./codes") {
            sh 'npm run test'
        }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

In my Node.js code, I'm trying to get access to those env variables by writing process.env.DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET but that is not working I am getting undefined ...
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Which type of credentials did you use: `secret text` or `username and password`?

While using `username and password` you can get username and password separately each other like this

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
      DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT = credentials('DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT')
  }
stages {
stage('Get username and password') {
  steps {
    echo "username is $DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_USR"
    echo "password is $DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_PSW"
  }
}
}
```

I don't know how to call $DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_USR and $DEV_GOOGLE_CLIENT_PSW in node.js, sorry.

Comment: Right, and In nodejs one could do process.env.<env var name>

Comment: I am using credentials for secret text,@PankajSaini didn't understand what you say can you explain plz?

Answer (score 1):

You pass your credentials in this order: `1 Jenkins credentials` > `2 pipeline environment variable` > `2 node.js command line parameter` > `3 node.js environment variable`

#### 1 Jenkins credentials

Make sure to create a Jenkins credentials as secret text first: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

#### 2 pipeline environment variable + node.js command line parameter

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  environment {
      JENKINS_SECRET_TEXT=credentials('JENKINS_SECRET_TEXT')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Pass secret as command line parameter') {
      steps {
        sh 'SECRET_ENV_VAR="$JENKINS_SECRET_TEXT" node app.js'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### 3 node.js

```js
console.log("SECRET_ENV_VAR:", process.env.SECRET_ENV_VAR);
```